# Reserved Word error

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, syntax-error

I have the following piece of code in **Coffee-script**

```
class @Badge
  setIssues: (count)->
    @count = count
    @render()
```

When I run my script, I get the following error ,

```
Uncaught Syntax-Error: Unexpected reserved word
```

I am complete newbie in `Coffee-script` , so totally off-guard as of how to fix this error

I tried removing the word **'class'** , hence removing the first line(including @Badge), as it is mentioned [here](https://github.com/rstacruz/js2coffee/pull/67) , that 'class' is a reserved word . On doing so , it resulted in the error ,

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token >
```

How can i fix this error ?

Comment: Your example works fine. Maybe the issue is somewhere else? Mixed tabs/spaces maybe?  See: http://coffeescript.org/#try:class%20%40Badge%0A%20%20setIssues%3A%20(count)-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%40count%20%3D%20count%0A%20%20%20%20%40render()

Comment: Oh and you probably don't want the `@` on your class name. Try it with just `class Badge`

Comment: Don't remove class, you want to use that word for it's reserved purpose. I'm not seeing a problem either, so asawyer is probably right. Unless we are both blind, maybe. Do check tabs/spaces, they get me all the time. Good research before hand though.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by tabs/spaces ? What should they be like ?I mean,where shud a tab come,where a space ?sorry if i m being absurd,but i m just total newbie to cofescript .

Comment: If you mix tabs and spaces in the indentation it can confuse the compiler. Make sure to use just one or the other. I prefer spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your two errors:

> Uncaught Syntax-Error: Unexpected reserved word
>   Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token >

suggest that you're trying to run CoffeeScript code as though it was JavaScript. You need to compile your CoffeeScript to JavaScript before you can run it in a JavaScript environment.

See the fine manual for details:

- [Usage](http://coffeescript.org/#usage)
- ["text/coffeescript" Script Tags](http://coffeescript.org/#scripts)